# Jinja 2, Columns don't fit

Tags: python, templates, pdf, jinja2

im use jinja2 for print pdf templates.
And i have this problem.
If i use array['1','2','3'], for printing. It works for my(example in screenshot)

[image]

But if i use array['1','2','3','4','5', '6'], i have this bug(example in screenshot)
[image]

How i can fix this?

MY JINJA TEMPLATE:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just change jinja code (Some text -> {% colspan etd_warranty_table_contents.col_labels|count %}Some text)